# How do I access an enum value in this class?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, enums, state, monogame

I am a fairly new programmer trying to make a pretty simple game by using MonoGame in C#. My problem is that I want to access an enum value (not sure if that's the right term) in this other class, but I don't know how. My guesses are that you could do something like: `return Game1.State.EnterHighScore;` or by making an object reference, but it has not worked for me, probably because I'm doing it incorrectly. 
I would appreciate help!

I'm sorry I don't know how to format the code properly, but I tried to make it as clear as possible:

```
//File name: GameElements.cs
//...
    //...
        //...
            //...   
                    if (e.CheckCollision(player)) 
                    {
                        player.IsAlive = false;
                        return /*EnterHighScore*/; // I want to return the enum value EnterHighscore, 
                                                   //..which is in the class Game1
                    }
            //...
        //...
    //...
//...
```

```
//File name: Game1.cs
//...
    public class Game1 : Game
    {
        enum State { PrintHighScore, EnterHighScore }; // I want to access EnterHighScore.
        //...
    }
//...
```

Comment: return Game1.State.EnterHighScore;  The enum has to be made public.

Comment: @jdweng I get the error message: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'SpaceShooter.Game1.State' to 'SpaceShooter.GameElements.State'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"

Comment: Can you edit your post and add more code for context?

Comment: Sounds like the return type is not `Game.State`, but instead `SpaceShooter.GameElements.State`, so what is that.  I'd suggest using unique names to not confuse them.

Comment: You probably should have your enum as a direct member of the namespace, not of any of the classes.

Comment: What is the return type of the method?  I think it is defined wrong.  It looks like you have a duplicate definition : 'SpaceShooter.GameElements.State.  Why is it plural (GameElements)?

Answer (score 1):

Keep your enum outside of any class. Then you can directly return from any method in any class in the same namespace.
eg:

```
public enum GameState
{
    EnterHighScore,
    EnterSomeOtherScore,
    EnterLooserScore
};

public class SomeClass
{
    public GameState CheckGame()
    {
        return GameState.EnterHighScore;
    }
}
```

If you keep the enum inside any class, then the scope of enum will be only to that class.